# TextFieldParser not skipping .CommentTokens-Lines

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.commenttokens%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I use a `TextFieldParser` to read a csv File:

```
    Sub imp1(path As String)
        With New TextFieldParser("C:\matrix1.csv")
            .TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            .Delimiters = New String() {";"}
            .CommentTokens = New String() {"'"}
            Debug.Print(.ReadToEnd)
            ' some more code to read the contents into a 2d-array
        End with
    End Sub
```

After setting `.CommentTokens = New String() {"'"}` I expected lines with leading single quotes being skipped.

However, from what I gather there is no difference at all when reading a csv like the following:

```
'comment1
1;0.5;0.9;0.3
0.5;1;0.6;0.2
0.9;0.6;1;0.1
0.3;0.2;0.1;1
```

I tried replacing the single quote `'` with several common comment-characters (`#`, `\`, `\*`), both with and without a following blanks - still not getting the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are using [`TextFieldParser.ReadToEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/274x8ct2(v=vs.90).aspx) which simply returns the complete remaining text and does not ignore comments. This is documented:

> The ReadToEnd method does not ignore blank lines and comments.

If you would use [`ReadFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.readfields(v=vs.110).aspx) the comments would be ignored (MS example):

```
While Not MyReader.EndOfData
    Try
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
        ' Include code here to handle the row.
    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & 
        " is invalid.  Skipping")
    End Try
End While
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Works perfectly. Ironically, I was only using `.ReadToEnd` and `.ReadLine` for testing and `.ReadFields` for my actual routine. I can't find the documentation for this exception here {https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.commenttokens%28v=vs.110%29.aspx}

Comment: @MartinDreher: Yes, unfortunately exception documentation is very poor in .NET/MSDN since .NET has not checked exceptions (like f.e. java). [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.malformedlineexception.aspx) is the `MalformedLineException `